# Targeting multiple frameworks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

I need to find a way to automatically build a solution that consists of 22 C# projects. The problem is I need to make two separate builds, one that targets the .NET 2.0 framework and another one that targets the .NET 4.0 framework.

I've been doing this manually, changing the target framework for each project individually and build.

My question is there a way in visual studio to make the switch automatically, something in the post build events that once the build for the first framework is done, then switch all project to a new target framework and start another build with the new framework?

BTW, I am using Visual Studio 2010 if that helps.

Comment: can you unload the projects with older framework, build and then restore them, change the framework again and unload the ones using the newer?

Comment: From an MSBuild perspective, I'd presume that you can create additional build configurations (like the default ones, *Debug* and *Release*), and set different target frameworks based on those configurations for each project. Like that, you'd only have to switch the build configuration for your solution later on and all the projects should adapt automatically. Not sure how to do that within VS, though.

Comment: Actually, this seems to be partially outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321757/how-to-build-same-project-with-multiple-configuration-c-sharp-visualstudio2012).

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 separate solutions, each containing all 22 projects.  Each solution would build to a different framework.  You would need to take care not to edit any one solution in such a way that the change would not be supported in the other.

Comment: I am considering this as an option actually, but I would rather have one solution to manage since you'll have to keep in mind that any new file or class added to one solution should be added to the other. And since these are gonna be different projects so I have to keep modifying back and forth.

Comment: I don't think VS natively has that capability, (without a 3rd party tool), but you could try creating MSBuild scripts or even use an automated build tool in which you could configure frameworks.

Comment: The project contains files and classes, not the solution. But The framework is on project level, so not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that has been adopted for the [Dapper project](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/) is

- have a project for each target platform.
- the source files are physically stored in one of the projects
- the source files are linked to the projects for other target platforms (use "Add as Link" in Visual Studio)

This can work reasonably well as long as the projects are stable - i.e. you are rarely adding new source files.

If your project is evolving the chore of adding new source files as links to multiple projects may become a burden.  In which case an automated version of your current manual solution might be best.  E.g. a script to copy a project in its entirety to a temporary location, change the target platform, and build.